# Question about GIT: when is the map $\pi:X//_\theta G\rightarrow X//G$ birational?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, geometric-invariant-theory

I want to ask somebody who is more familiar with the theory of GIT quotients than I am, if there is a nice list of conditions on the action of a reductive group $G$ on an affine variety $X$ over algebraically closed field of char $0$, that imply that the map $\pi:X/\!\!/_\theta G\rightarrow X/\!\!/G$ is birational.

I can write down the following list, but I'm not satisfied with it because it is essentially a tautology.

1) The union of closed $G$-orbits is dense in $X$.

2) There is a $\theta$-semistable point in each irreducible component of $X$.

I was thinking may be there is a nice way to check if the orbit of a $\theta$-semistable point is closed, something like: if the point is $\theta$-semistable and $-\theta$-semistable, then the orbit is closed, but I'm not sure if something like that is indeed true.

Comment: You may want to have a look into Thaddeus or Dolgachev-Hu papers.